# From which memory area is my string called?

Tags: java, string, methods, static, static-methods

```
public class Do {

    static String s="Instance";

    public static void method(String s){
        s="Add";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Do d=new Do();
        s="new Instance";
        String s="Local";
        method(s);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(d.s);
    }
}
```

output is:

```
Local

new Instance
```

Here I am making a static global variable as "Instance" and after that I am again initializing it with "New Instance" in the main method.
My question is in which memory area "Instance", "New Instance" and "Local" will go and how?

Comment: They will all go into the String Constants pool (Metaspace in Java 8)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared a String variable without using a new keyword, they'll be getting a place in String Constant Pool. I don't see any part of confusion with this code. If you had declared the variable like

```
String s = new String("local");
```

Then this would have been created on heap as well as String constant pool.
But the main point of knowing the changes in String pool is that from java 1.7, the String pool has been shifted to heap and you're no more limited with fixed size permgen space.

Comment: I know that but Just justify the output line by line as it is coming like:                                        "local" and "New Instance". And where and how s="Instance" is saving and where s="local" is saving?